# How to reduce the full screen mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, fullscreen

I have a little problem when I'm in the full screen mode in emacs , how can 
return to the default mode , for more explanation this is my problem .

I open a file in full-screen mode with emacs -fs filename.txt, after i want to  reduce it to default or normal mode (size) . and thanks a lot for your help and your time I really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

F11 - Toggle Full Screen Mode.

Comment: Does F11 toggle full screen mode?

Answer (score 1):

I found this [on EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen#toc24) the other day:

```
(defun toggle-fullscreen ()
  "Toggle full screen"
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-parameter
     nil 'fullscreen
     (when (not (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen)) 'fullboth)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can revert the fullscreen parameter of a frame by eval'ing following code:

```
(modify-frame-parameters (selected-frame) '((fullscreen . nil)))
```

You may also modify programatically the size of current frame with

```
 (set-frame-size (selected-frame) COLS ROWS)
```

As long as the property fullscreen has been set to nil before.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but i want to see if there are some emacs keyboard shortcuts to return to the normal mode , any idea ??

Comment: You can easily assign a shortcut of your choice to the above two lines of code (put it into an interactive function and use `global-set-key`).  You need to define how many columns and rows are "normal" for you.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Keybindings.html#Keybindings and http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Writing-Defuns.html#Writing-Defuns for help on how to define the function and create the shortcut.

Comment: it's the default size of emacs on linux machines